# R: Basic conversion of 1 and 0 to TRUE and FALSE is failing

Tags: r

It's been a while since I've use R, and I need a refresher on basic functionality (amazingly, I can't readily find this on Google).

This fails. It does nothing, with no messages. Closing and reloading View(df) in RStudio shows df$Valid is still 0's and 1's.

```
df$Valid[df$Valid == 1] <- TRUE  
df$Valid[df$Valid == 0] <- FALSE
```

df$Valid is the default type of double, read in from a .csv with readr::readcsv()

Comment: I meant to post this to stackoverflow.  Where's the delete option??????  I just see share, cite, edit, flag.

Comment: Please migrate this to stackoverflow.  It says I can only post there once every 90 minutes.  I guess I blocked by posting here, as this is a new account.

Comment: don't worry, we'll try to get it migrated :)

Answer (score 5):

This will replace the existing `Valid` variable with True or False according to the condition, which is what it seems you were trying to do

```
df$Valid <- df$Valid == 1
```

Comment: Thanks for another way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Robert's answer is the easiest way to do this however, your attempt failed because you can have data of only one type in a vector. When you are doing

```
df$Valid[df$Valid == 1] <- TRUE
```

You also have data in `Valid` where `Valid = 0` which is numeric so `TRUE` value is coerced to 1 again to keep the data type consistent in the vector. You attempt will work if you do this in a new column.

```
df$newvalid <- NA
df$newvalid[df$Valid == 1] <- TRUE  
df$newvalid[df$Valid == 0] <- FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this toy example:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 1, 0), var2= c(1.001, 1.00001, 0.0001))
> df
  var1    var2
1    1 1.00100
2    1 1.00001
3    0 0.00010
> # let's convert the first variable
> df$var1 <- sapply(df$var1, as.logical)
> df
   var1    var2
1  TRUE 1.00100
2  TRUE 1.00001
3 FALSE 0.00010
> # let's convert the second variable
> df$var2 <- sapply(df$var2, as.integer)
> df$var2 <- sapply(df$var2, as.logical)
> df
   var1  var2
1  TRUE  TRUE
2  TRUE  TRUE
3 FALSE FALSE
```

Please note that, for var2 (which is double), we need first to recast it in integer.

Comment: `df$var1 <- sapply(df$var1, as.logical)` can just be `df$var1 <- as.logical(df$var1)` (same for other transformations)

Comment: Thanks for a working solution.  Why won't it let me do the assignment, as I wrote it?  My attempted assignment doesn't work if it's an integer, either.

Comment: John, when mixed types are in a vector, they are converted to the simplest type that can hold each element. eg, `c(TRUE, 0)` is converted to `c(1, 0)` while `c("T", 0)` is converted to `c("T", "0")`

Comment: See eg https://www.r-bloggers.com/type-conversion-and-you-or-and-r/ R *is* letting you do the assignment, but it's converting `TRUE` to its numerical value (`1`) and same with `FALSE` (`0`)

Comment: @alanocallaghan - Okay, now I get it.  Thanks.

Comment: Cheers! Still something that catches me out sometimes. Especially irritating with matrices :)

Comment: Just to note, as.logical works with a double.  And it converts 0.0001 to TRUE, so, don't do that.